# XSLT Mapping: Is there any way I can get the mapping(which input fields map to which output field - csv/excel) by parsing a xslt?

Tags: excel, xslt, mapping

Situation: So, I manage a XSLT at work. Also, developed by me. The thing is that recently, there have been lot of consumers(of the output that my XSLT generates) demanding a mapping between the input and output that my XSLT generates.

Problem: I have never maintained a mapping, for example an excel sheet that has the x-path of the output field and the logic around the input fields(along with their x-paths) used to populate that output field.

What I tried: Using a XSLT to read that XSLT as I thought it would be easier as XSLT itself is kind of a XML.

Issue I am facing: It is difficult. Lot of things to consider. Will it be worth the effort? Or is it even possible?

Is there any other way I can do this? If it can be done.
Is there some kind of software already available?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the question is too vague. I don't think there's a generic way to produce such "mapping" for every possible combination of XSL and XSLT.

If your mapping is one-to-one, you could write a simple stylesheet that takes your XML and replaces all text values with the path to their parent nodes. Then transforming the result with your existing XSLT stylesheet to obtain a table listing the source path of each target cell.

But this will not work in those places where your stylesheet changes the processed values in any way.